# how do I get an angle from a slope?

Tags: java

so i am currently making a game, i needed to get the angle from a slope for an AI that im working on in the game. however,  it doesnt work how i expect it to and it only happens when i use this function i made after doing a few hours of research.

keep in mind, i only learned up to algebra and geometry 1 in school, i have been trying to teach myself algebra and geometry 2 as well as calculus in my free time.

```
public static double angleFromSlope(double rise, double run)
{
    double r;
    if (run == 0.0)
    {
        r = (Math.atan(0) * 180 / Math.PI);
    } else if (rise == 0.0)
    {
        r = (Math.atan(0) * 180 / Math.PI);
    } else
    {
        r = (Math.atan(rise / run) * 180 / Math.PI);
    }

    if (rise >= 0 && run >= 0)
    {
        return r;
    }

    else if (rise >= 0 && run <= 0)
    {
        return Math.abs(r + 90) + 90;
    }

    else if (rise < 0 && run < 0)
    {
        return Math.abs(Math.abs(r) + 180);
    }

    else
    {
        return Math.abs(r + 90) + 270;
    }

}
```

edit:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double angle = 90;

    double[] dir = DirFromAngle(angle);

    System.out.println(dir[0] + " " + dir[1]);

    double[] line = new double[]
    { 10, 10, 10 + (dir[0] * 10), 10 + (dir[1] * 10) };

    double[] rn = riseOverRun(line);

    double a = angleFromSlope(rn[0], rn[1]);

    System.out.println(a);

}

public static double[] DirFromAngle(double angle)
{
    double b = Math.toRadians(angle);

    double[] output = new double[]
    { Math.sin(b), Math.cos(b) };
    return output;
}

public static double[] riseOverRun(double[] line)
{
    // 0 - X1, 1 - Y1, 2 - X2, 3 - Y2
    double[] output = new double[]
    { (line[3] - line[1]), (line[2] - line[0]) };
    return output;
}

public static double angleFromSlope(double rise, double run)
{
    double r;
    if (run == 0.0)
    {
        r = (Math.atan(0) * 180 / Math.PI);
    } else if (rise == 0.0)
    {
        r = (Math.atan(0) * 180 / Math.PI);
    } else
    {
        r = (Math.atan(rise / run) * 180 / Math.PI);
    }

    if (rise >= 0 && run >= 0)
    {
        return r;
    }

    else if (rise >= 0 && run <= 0)
    {
        return Math.abs(r + 90) + 90;
    }

    else if (rise < 0 && run < 0)
    {
        return Math.abs(Math.abs(r) + 180);
    }

    else
    {
        return Math.abs(r + 90) + 270;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by *"it doesnt work how i expect it to"*? I've just tested it with some values and it gives me the right angle except for negative arguments. Is it that?

Comment: what i mean by "it doesnt work how i expect it to" is when i send a ray from the angle givin by this function, the ray gets tested to see if it collides with any lines. if it does, the ray saves the closest collision point as well as the distance. im entering the slope of the AI to the player so it always looks in the players direction. it then tests the distance of the closest object it sees and the player location. if the player location is less than the distance of the closest object, the AI enters chase mode.

Comment: i did some testing and noticed the ray isnt going in the correct angle. and it cant be the ray because the player also uses the rays and that works fine. (ray casting engine)

Comment: But it's `angleFromSlope` that the question is about, right? Could you provide some *expected input -> expected output* for the function? Involving working cases and not working cases.

Comment: i added the code i was testing with to the question under "edit" i was expecting the output to be 90, but it ends up being 0

Comment: Okay, I've placed `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rn));` right before the `angleFromSlope` call and I get `[0.0, 10.0]`. Are those values correct at that point?

Comment: You're essentially trying to re-implement [Math#atan2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-), right?

Comment: what im trying to do here is convert an angle into a 2D direction, then take that 2D direction and turn it back into an angle, but i need the angles to mach. if you mess around with the angle  variable and place any number between (0 - 359) it doesnt return the same number.

Comment: "keep in mind, i only learned up to algebra and geometry 1 in school, i have been trying to teach myself algebra and geometry 2 as well as calculus in my free time." - That should teach you that "coding" (not developing software) ain't easy. Engineering software is a science and as such, it requires vast knowledge.

Comment: @akuzminykh - i realized i didnt answer your question on if [0.0, 10.0] was correct. yes it is. the riseOverRun funtion is suppose to return a double[] {rise, run}.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, thanks though for trying to help me. all i had to do was

```
answer = Math.abs(Math.abs(answer - 360) + 90);

if (answer > 259)
{
    answer -= 360;
} else if (answer < 0)
{
    answer += 360;
}
```

in the fallowing funtion

```
public static double angleFromSlope(double rise, double run)
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#000.00");

    double r;

    double answer;

    r = (Math.atan(rise / run) * 180 / Math.PI);

    if (rise >= 0 && run >= 0)
    {
        answer = r;
    }

    else if (rise >= 0 && run <= 0)
    {
        answer = Math.abs(r + 90) + 90;
    }

    else if (rise < 0 && run < 0)
    {
        answer = Math.abs(Math.abs(r) + 180);
    }

    else
    {
        answer = Math.abs(r + 90) + 270;
    }

    answer = Math.abs(Math.abs(answer - 360) + 90);

    if (answer > 259)
    {
        answer -= 360;
    } else if (answer < 0)
    {
        answer += 360;
    }

    return Double.valueOf(df.format(answer));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use Point and Line to explain what you want to calculate. A point contains x, y and a line has 2 points. Draw out the shape can also make better understanding.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AngleFromSlope extends Canvas {
    protected static class Point {
        private final double x, y;
        
        protected Point(double x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("(");
            builder.append(x);
            builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(y);
            builder.append(")");
            return builder.toString();
        }               
        
    }
    
    protected static class Line {
        private final Point p1, p2;
        
        protected Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("[");
            builder.append(p1);
            builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(p2);
            builder.append("]");
            return builder.toString();
        }               
        
    }
    
    protected List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();                
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_DISABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            int m = getHeight()/2;
            g2d.translate(0, m);
            // flip about y-axis
            g2d.scale(1,-1);
            // first shift "up" (negative) m pixels
            g2d.translate(0,-m);
            
            for(Line line : lines) {
                g2d.drawLine((int) line.p1.x, (int) line.p1.y, (int) line.p2.x, (int) line.p2.y);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
    } 

    public static void main(String [] args) throws java.io.IOException {        
        AngleFromSlope canvas = new AngleFromSlope();
        java.awt.Frame frame = new java.awt.Frame("AngleFromSlope");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);
        
        final int SCALE = 50;
        final int BASE = 4, HEIGHT = 4;

        Point a = new Point(SCALE, SCALE);
        Point b = new Point(SCALE + BASE * SCALE, SCALE);
        Point c = new Point(SCALE + BASE * SCALE, SCALE + HEIGHT * SCALE);
        Line line1 = new Line(a, b);
        canvas.lines.add(line1);

        Line line2 = new Line(a, c);        
        canvas.lines.add(line2);
        Line line3 = new Line(b, c);
        canvas.lines.add(line3);
        
        double slope = (c.y - a.y) / (c.x - a.x);
        System.out.println("Slope: " + slope);

        double theta = Math.atan(slope);  
        System.out.println("θ: " + Math.toDegrees(theta));

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) { 
                System.out.println("Closing program");      
                System.exit(0); }
        } );        

    }
}
```